# Overlay images and block in beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, transparency

I found this slides on Internet with a very nice style.
http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~tov/pubs/alms/alms-popl2011-slides.pdf

How can I overlay blocks and image as in this slides?
Specially this effect:

[image: (Overlayed boxes)]

Comment: This should be possible by using `beamer`s overlays together with [How can I position an image in an arbitrary position in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16357/2975). I'm sure someone will write a solution for it. I would, but I don't have much time today.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can provide you a very basic solution: it is not perfect, but actually does what you wonder.

Initially I defined two `tikzstyle`s to characterize whether the block is alerted or not:

```
\tikzset{visib/.style={rectangle,color=blue,fill=blue!10,text=black,draw,text opacity=0.4, text width=#1,align=flush center}}
\tikzset{invisib/.style={rectangle,color=gray,fill=gray!10,text=black,draw,text opacity=0.4, text width=#1,align=flush center}}
```

Then I defined an environment where to insert blocks:

```
\newenvironment{myfancyblock}%
{\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}}%
{\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}}%
```

and the key command:

```
\newcommand{\opaqueblock}[4]{
\node<#1>[#2=#3] (X) {#4};
}
```

where:

- ## 1 gives you the *overlay specification*
- ## 2 which *style* are you using (*visib* or *invisib*)
- ## 3 the width of the block
- ## 4 the text you want to put in the block.

Look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

% command to highlight text in orange
\newcommand{\alertor}[1]{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}

\tikzset{visib/.style={rectangle,color=blue,fill=blue!10,text=black,draw,text opacity=0.4, text width=#1,align=flush center}}
\tikzset{invisib/.style={rectangle,color=gray,fill=gray!10,text=black,draw,text opacity=0.4, text width=#1,align=flush center}}

\newenvironment{myfancyblock}{\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}}{\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}}

\newcommand{\opaqueblock}[4]{
\node<#1>[#2=#3] (X) {#4};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My frame with footnotes} 

\begin{myfancyblock}
\opaqueblock{1}{visib}{\textwidth}{All you have to do to initialize a GLSurfaceView is call setRenderer().
However, if desired, you can modify the default behavior of GLSurfaceView
by calling \alertor{one or more} of these methods before \alertor{setRenderer}:
\begin{itemize}
\item setDebug()
\item setChooser()
\item setWrapper()
\end{itemize}
\begin{flushright}
(Android    2.2 API Reference)
\end{flushright}
}
\opaqueblock{2-}{invisib}{\textwidth}{All you have to do to initialize a GLSurfaceView is call setRenderer().
However, if desired, you can modify the default behavior of GLSurfaceView
by calling \alertor{one or more} of these methods before \alertor{setRenderer}:
\begin{itemize}
\item setDebug()
\item setChooser()
\item setWrapper()
\end{itemize}
\begin{flushright}
(Android    2.2 API Reference)
\end{flushright}
}

\opaqueblock{2}{visib}{0.6\textwidth}{You can optionally modify the behaviour of GLSurfaceView by calling one or more debugging methods \alertor{setDebug()}, and \alertor{setWrapper()}. These methods can be called \alertor{before and or after setRender}}
\opaqueblock{3-}{invisib}{0.6\textwidth}{You can optionally modify the behaviour of GLSurfaceView by calling one or more debugging methods \alertor{setDebug()}, and \alertor{setWrapper()}. These methods can be called \alertor{before and or after setRender}}

\opaqueblock{3}{visib}{0.7\textwidth}{Once the render is set, you can control whether the render draws continuously or on demand by calling \alertor{setRenderMode()}}

\end{myfancyblock}

\visible<3->{
This is stuff text:
\begin{itemize}
\item hello
\item hello
\item hello again
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Since it is a very basic solution, it has some drawbacks: first you need to specify twice the same text using both styles *visib* and *invisib* although I would have been able to let things happen automatically. Second the text alignment is always centered, but I thought that inserting a further argument would have been too much heavy.

The result is shown in the following frames:

[image]

> **IMPROVEMENT**

To cope with issues mentioned above, here is an improvement to my solution. The basic idea is to store the text put in a *visib* block to subsequently recall it when using an *invisib* block. To do so I defined two commands:

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{thistext}
\newcommand{\savetext}[2]{%
  «#1»%
  \addtocounter{thistext}{1}%
  \@namedef{thistext\thethistext}{#2}}
\newcommand{\printthistext}[1]{\@nameuse{thistext#1}}
\makeatother
```

changed the previous `\opaqueblock` into:

```
\newcommand{\opaqueblock}[3]{
\node<#1>[visib=#2] (X) {#3};
\savetext{mytext}{#3}
}
```

(no more need of the argument to select the type of block) and defined a new command just for *invisib* blocks:

```
\newcommand{\invblock}[2]{
\node<#1>[invisib=#2] (X) {\printthistext{\thethistext}};
}
```

Moreover I changed the `text alignment` in the definition of blocks:

```
\tikzset{visib/.style={rectangle,color=blue,fill=blue!10,text=black,draw,text opacity=0.4, text width=#1,align=justify}}
\tikzset{invisib/.style={rectangle,color=gray,fill=gray!10,text=black,draw,text opacity=0.4, text width=#1,align=justify}}
```

Thus the MWE could be simplified into:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

% command to highlight text in orange
\newcommand{\alertor}[1]{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}

\tikzset{visib/.style={rectangle,color=blue,fill=blue!10,text=black,draw,text opacity=0.4, text width=#1,align=justify}}
\tikzset{invisib/.style={rectangle,color=gray,fill=gray!10,text=black,draw,text opacity=0.4, text width=#1,align=justify}}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{thistext}
\newcommand{\savetext}[2]{%
  «#1»%
  \addtocounter{thistext}{1}%
  \@namedef{thistext\thethistext}{#2}}
\newcommand{\printthistext}[1]{\@nameuse{thistext#1}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{myfancyblock}{\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}}{\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}}

\newcommand{\opaqueblock}[3]{
\node<#1>[visib=#2] (X) {#3};
\savetext{mytext}{#3}
}

\newcommand{\invblock}[2]{
\node<#1>[invisib=#2] (X) {\printthistext{\thethistext}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My frame with footnotes} 

\begin{myfancyblock}
% First block
\opaqueblock{1}{\textwidth}{All you have to do to initialize a GLSurfaceView is call setRenderer().
However, if desired, you can modify the default behavior of GLSurfaceView
by calling \alertor{one or more} of these methods before \alertor{setRenderer}:
\begin{itemize}
\item setDebug()
\item setChooser()
\item setWrapper()
\end{itemize}
\begin{flushright}
(Android    2.2 API Reference)
\end{flushright}
}
\invblock{2-}{\textwidth}

% Second block
\opaqueblock{2}{0.6\textwidth}{You can optionally modify the behaviour of GLSurfaceView by calling one or more debugging methods \alertor{setDebug()}, and \alertor{setWrapper()}. These methods can be called \alertor{before and or after setRender}}
\invblock{3-}{0.6\textwidth}

% Third block
\opaqueblock{3}{0.7\textwidth}{Once the render is set, you can control whether the render draws continuously or on demand by calling \alertor{setRenderMode()}}

\end{myfancyblock}

\visible<3->{
This is stuff text:
\begin{itemize}
\item hello
\item hello
\item hello again
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now the only requirement is to put `\invblock` just after the definition of a `\opaqueblock` to print the correct text. The graphical result is:

[image]

> **Implementation with the [`dynblocks`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dynblocks) package**

Note: the version `0.2a` is required.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{dynblocks}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

% command to highlight text in orange
\newcommand{\alertor}[1]{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My frame with footnotes} 

\begin{dynblock}
% First block
\opaqueblock<1>{All you have to do to initialize a GLSurfaceView is call setRenderer().
However, if desired, you can modify the default behavior of GLSurfaceView
by calling \alertor{one or more} of these methods before \alertor{setRenderer}:
\begin{itemize}
\item setDebug()
\item setChooser()
\item setWrapper()
\end{itemize}
\begin{flushright}
(Android    2.2 API Reference)
\end{flushright}
}
\invblock<2->

% Second block
\opaqueblock<2>[0.6\textwidth]{You can optionally modify the behaviour of GLSurfaceView by calling one or more debugging methods \alertor{setDebug()}, and \alertor{setWrapper()}. These methods can be called \alertor{before and or after setRender}}
\invblock<3->

% Third block
\opaqueblock<3>[0.7\textwidth]{Once the render is set, you can control whether the render draws continuously or on demand by calling \alertor{setRenderMode()}}

\end{dynblock}

\visible<3->{
This is stuff text:
\begin{itemize}
\item hello
\item hello
\item hello again
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16357/2975), as already mentioned by  Martin in his comment, demonstrates the general ways to approach absolute positioning by using `textpos` or `tikz` in beamer.

**Warning:** `texpos` interacts badly on the shipout level with `pgfpages` (the `pgfpages` transformations are not applied to the content that has been inserted via `textpos`). If you also need `pgfpages` for two-screen-support or preparing n-up handouts, you should use `tikz` or [apply this trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53606/3751) from Andrew Stacey to prevent the problem.

However, in your specific case you might as well use a simple hack by inserting a negative `\vskip` before the overlay block:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{rose}  % for 'visible' blocks


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mylist}{%
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Subitem 
        \item Subitem
          \begin{itemize}
            \item Subsubitem 
            \item Subsubitem
          \end{itemize}
        \item Subitem
        \item Subitem
      \end{itemize}
    \item Item
    \item Item
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Subitem 
        \item Subitem
        \item Subitem
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame}
  \mylist
  \pause
  \vskip-3cm
  \begin{block}{The Overlay Block}
    Block Text
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and simple solution, I like it !

Answer (score 7):

Seeing the remaining slides, I think there is a heavy use of TikZ in this document and I think everything is a TikZ node instead of blocks. So here is a quick stab at Beamer/PGF interplay. There might be easier ways in terms of the effect but PGF based commands are the shortest path for me so far. There is a `remember picture,overlay` option in action so make sure you run it twice.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\opaqalert}[2]{\alt<#1>{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\alert{#2}\pgfsetfillopacity{0.2}}{#2}}
\begin{frame}[t]{Example: OpenGL on Android}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}   
    \only<2->{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.2}\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.2}}
    \node[thick,draw=red,draw,text width=\textwidth,inner color=white,outer color=red!10] (n1) at (0,0) {
    All you have to do to initialize a GLSurfaceView is call \texttt{setRenderer()}. However, 
    if desired, you can modify the default behavior of GLSurfaceView by calling 
    \opaqalert{2}{one or more} of these methods before \opaqalert{2}{\texttt{setRenderer}}:
     \begin{itemize}
     \item \opaqalert{2}{\texttt{setDebug()}}
     \item \opaqalert{2}{\texttt{setChooser()}}
     \item \opaqalert{2}{\texttt{setWrapper()}}.\hfill(Android 2.2 API Reference)
     \end{itemize}
    };
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
    \node<3->[thick,draw=red,draw,text width=0.9\textwidth,inner color=white,outer color=red!10] (n2) at (0,0) {
    \only<3->{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.2}\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.2}}
    You can optionally modify the behavior of GLSurfaceView
    by calling one or more of the debugging methods \opaqalert{3}{\texttt{setDebug()}},
    and \opaqalert{3}{\texttt{setWrapper()}}. These methods may be called before
    and/or after \opaqalert{3}{\texttt{setRenderer}},...};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
    \node<4->[thick,draw=red,draw,text width=\textwidth,inner color=white,outer color=red!10] (n3) at (0,0) {
    \only<4->{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.2}\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.2}}
    \opaqalert{4}{Once the renderer is set}, you can control whether the renderer draw continuously
    or on demand by calling \opaqalert{4}{\texttt{setRenderMode()}}.};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill<5>[fill=white,opacity=0.8] (current page.north east) rectangle (current page.south west);
\node<5> at (current page.center){\huge Typestate};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I still think that it's not a good idea to overlay text as authors did. It doesn't convey the message and there is an excessive use of overlays. To be honest if I was in this talk I would be wondering about how the nodes are overlayed instead of the content. Especially frame 5 has the cardinal sin of presentation rules (maybe they deliberately wanted to give a confusion effect). I noticed a shading in the background quite later for example. I hate to sound like a stupid life coach but indeed *less is more* in this case.

By the way, I didn't try it but those boxes can be `beamercolorbox` es inside the nodes.