# Beamer ovalbox frame thickness

Tags: beamer, framed

I'm working with Beamer and I would like to create boxes with round corners. I use `\ovalbox`, but I would like to control the thickness of the line. How can I do this? I also tried `\thinlines`, but I still not understand the sintax since I didn't find a minimal example.

Comment: Do you mean something like the box created in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59826/position-an-exampleblock-in-front-of-content/59836#59836)?

Comment: No, I would like a framed word as created by \ovalbox{hello}, for instance. But I need to control the thikness of the line.

Comment: I can't find in which package ovalbox is defined. It appears not to be part of beamer. Are you using fancybox, perhaps?

Comment: The beamer user guide says: `More frame types are offered by the package fancybox, which defines the following commands:\shadowbox, \doublebox, \ovalbox, and \Ovalbox`, so to use those commands you should load the `fancybox` package.

Comment: Ok, so if fancybox is being used, use \Ovalbox instead of \ovalbox to get a thicker border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution based on Ti*k*Z which leads to:

[image]

Basically, all boxes are realized by means of a command, `\tframed`, defined as:

```
\newcommand{\tframed}[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(h.base)]\node[rndblock,#1] (h) {#2};}
```

where the `rndblock` style is:

```
\tikzset{rndblock/.style={rounded corners,rectangle,draw,outer sep=0pt}}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Style definition
\tikzset{rndblock/.style={rounded corners,rectangle,draw,outer sep=0pt}}

% Command Definition
% 1 optional to customize the aspect, 2 mandatory: text to be framed
\newcommand{\tframed}[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(h.base)]\node[rndblock,#1] (h) {#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is text \tframed[line width=2bp]{hello} {\tiny\tframed[red]{hello again} } \tframed[draw=red,line width=0.1pt]{word} this is other text    \\

This is text \tframed[line width=3bp,fill=green!50]{hello} {\tiny\tframed[blue,fill=blue!10]{hello again} } \tframed[text=red,line width=0.1pt]{word} this is other text    
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

To choose the options, especially the `line width`, you can refer to the pgfmanual (version October 25, 2010) 15.3.1 Graphic Parameters: Line Width, Line Cap, and Line Join.

> **IMPROVEMENT**

Here is a way to add overlay specifications to the `\tframed` command; the solution is based on the nice code provided by Daniel in  [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/tikzpicture-in-beamer/55849#55849). Basically this allows to not modify at all the previos definition of `\tframed` thus IMHO is very suitable in this case. Indeed, overlay specification can be added simply in the optional argument by means of `visible on=<*overlay specification*>`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%% Overlay definition
% based on Daniel's code
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/tikzpicture-in-beamer/55849#55849
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={text opacity=1,opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
    },
  }

%%% Style definition
\tikzset{rndblock/.style={rounded corners,rectangle,draw,outer sep=0pt}}

%%% Command Definition
% 1 optional to customize the aspect, 2 mandatory: text to be framed
\newcommand{\tframed}[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(h.base)]\node[rndblock,#1] (h) {#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is text \tframed[line width=2bp,visible on=<3->]{hello} {\tiny\tframed[red,visible on=<2->]{hello again}} \tframed[draw=red,line width=0.1pt,visible on=<4->]{word} this is other text    \\

This is text \tframed[line width=3bp,fill=green!50,visible on=<4->]{hello} {\tiny\tframed[blue,fill=blue!10,visible on=<3->]{hello again}} \tframed[text=red,line width=0.1pt,visible on=<2->]{word} this is other text    
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]