# How to highlight words or sentences?

Tags: color, framed, highlighting, mdframed

I would like to create something similar to [image].

To begin with, I would like to create a rounded and background-colored highlight of a word (or a short series of words).

What package should I use ?

How should I do ?

PS : I am not a Tikz user.

Comment: Do you want this feature for a figure/graph or in the text?

Comment: I need it in the text.

Comment: One way is described in [Beamer ovalbox frame thickness](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62415/13304).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125162/rounded-box-around-placeholder-text-that-supports-line-breaking/

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am using Latex and not Context.

Comment: This answer at that question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125162/rounded-box-around-placeholder-text-that-supports-line-breaking/125319#125319) works in LaTeX

Comment: @Colas: even if you're not TikZ user, it doesn't mean that you can't use the solution I suggested (just matter of copying three lines of code) or you can't use the nice answer suggested by Steven. As you need to do that job, you have to use some technique: word highlighting doesn't come for free. You might also want to have a look to [`fancybox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancybox).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I agree with you. I sometimes think why not ask if the task would take 3 seconds to someone as opposed to 2 hours for me. I think I will go with your solution. My (small) problem was about understanding the syntax for the optional arguments. I will manage. Thanks again.