# How to insert `beamercolorbox` above other contents? (beamer)

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I would like to add a bibliographic reference on my second slide. The contents of the bibliographic reference should be placed above all other contents. I tried the following, but the problem is that on the second slide, the `beamercolorbox` doesn't appear in front of the image. It is rather on the bottom

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\insertshortauthor}

\definecolor{Green}{HTML}{9BBB59}

\title{Some title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MyFrame}
    \visible<2>{
        \scriptsize{\setbeamercolor{postit}{bg=Green}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em,wd=\textwidth]{postit}
         \textit{A bibliography will be here!}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
                    }
                }
    \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
    \vspace{15pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
            Some text to the left
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(330,70){\makebox(0,0)[rt]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}}}
      \end{picture} 
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}


    \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
    \vspace{15pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
            More text to the left
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(310,55){\makebox(0,0)[rt]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}}
      \end{picture} 
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{10pt}

    \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
    \vspace{15pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
            Even more text to the left
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(200,50){\makebox(0,0)[rt]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}}}
      \end{picture} 
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Could you help me to achieve what I want? Any suggestions? Thank you!!

This is now:
[image]
But I want to have the green box above all other contents.

Comment: To avoid changes in contents size, use `\visible` for overlay.

Comment: I've updated the question with a image using `\visible`, but still is not what I want... the green box should be above all other contents

Comment: I read pretty much the entire `beamer` manual when I was learning it. I do not remember seeing anything related to the priority of contents appearance when they overlap. I would like to see the answer to this question as well

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh I've just added the solution for this problem. At least was I wanted to achieve :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer based on this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59844/108710

The package to use is called `textpos`. 
Before the `\begin{document}` have to add `\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}` and the `\visible<2>{...}` block have to change for the following:

```
\only<2>{
    \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(10mm,0.34\textheight)
            \scriptsize{\setbeamercolor{postit}{bg=Green}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em,wd=\textwidth]{postit}
             \textit{A bibliography will be here!}
            \end{beamercolorbox}
                        }
    \end{textblock*} 
}
```

NOTE: with `\visible<2>{..}` didn't work for me.[image]

The result can be seen in the image