# beamer: making a slide transparent and superimposing the next slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, transparency

Here is a slide.
The slide before was the one that we still see in the background.
It then became blue and transparent, and the problem line showed up.

[image]

Is that possible to use `tikZ` to arrive at a *similar* result? If so, can you provide a minimal example so that I can build on it?

Comment: Maybe [overlay-images-and-block-in-beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53784/overlay-images-and-block-in-beamer) can give you some hints

Comment: @percuße: Thank you for this interesting link. However, it is difficult for me to go through this long post and I cannot figure out which is the best solution for my purpose. I am pretty new to LaTeX, beamer, and tikZ... By the way, I'd like the whole slide to get 'transparent', not only a block. Is it still possible to adapt the solution from the other post. Would it be too much to ask a minimal example here?

Comment: One possibility is to typeset the code in the background using [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package, convert the pdf output into png, then make the result as a background as tikz node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution is based on TikZ. It provides a command `\superimpose<overlay spec>[TikZ option for node]{node text}` that draws a blue rectangle with 50 percent opacity over the complete slide and then typesets a TikZ node on top of it with the given text.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily
}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}

\newcommand<>{\superimpose}[2][]{%
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{%
    \filldraw#3[blue!30,opacity=0.5](current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
    \node#3[at=(current page),#1]{#2};
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{A Listing}
  \lstset{language=C, gobble=4}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
       printf("Hello World!");  
       return 0;
    }
  \end{lstlisting}
  \superimpose<2>[draw=red, fill=white]{Problem: ugly syntax}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks nice ! Let me read it carefully, and I will accept it thereafter (probably tomorrow morning)!

Comment: @user7064: It's absolutely okay to wait for a couple of days before accepting the answer that has helped you most. Not doing it too quickly often increases the chance of further answers that might help you even more :-)

Comment: Ok, it exactly fits my purpose :-) (+1). One more question please: instead of a single text line, is it possible to include, for example, \begin{itmize} ... \end{itemize}?

Comment: @user7064: Sure. In this case you should give the node a defined width. Add something like `text width=0.5\textwidth` to the list of node options and then put your `itemize` environment in the curly braces of the node text. You may also put a beamer box there.

Comment: Ok, nice that it looks simple. But, what node are you speaking about exactly?

Comment: @user7064: `\superimpose<2>[draw=red,fill=white,text width=0.5\textwidth]{\begin{itemize} \item ... \item ... \end{itemize}}`