# How to avoid the extra box at the end of the handout created by pgfpages?

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beamer handout: Problem when creating border around frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53505/beamer-handout-problem-when-creating-border-around-frames)

I am using `pgfpages` to create `handouts`. Here is my `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, handout,xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{\usetheme{CambridgeUS}}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper,border shrink=10mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First}
\begin{itemize}
\item check1
\item check 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Text 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Text 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As number of slides is odd, this code creates an empty box to fill the last page. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this issue.

Comment: Take a look at my solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53606/86 I think it does what you want (though will need adapting to the 2-on-1 layout).

Comment: Great!  In this sort of situation we would close this question as a duplicate of the other one to make it easier for others to find the answer, unless you needed to do some non-trivial adaptations to make it work in which case you could answer your own question.