# Export Beamer doc to 2 slides per page

Tags: beamer, pdftex, output

I'm a total LaTeX/beamer newbie looking for a way to export a slide deck I created into a sort of "book" form. I tried "handout" but that didn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Basically, I want to create a LETTER sized document with 2 frames on each page. Seems simple, but I'm having a hard time finding examples of doing anything similar online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This is pretty easy with `pdfnup`. See, for example [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53560/3751) on a usage example.

Comment: See section 21 of `texdoc beameruserguide`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
  \usepackage{pgfpages}
\mode<handout>{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black!20}}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper,border shrink=5mm]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Frame A
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame B
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame C
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame D
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the key package is `pgfpages` here with option `2 on 1` so that two frames per page are printed.
I added some background color to show where the frames are actually placed.
See the [Beamer User Guide](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) section 4.6.2 for more options (and section 58 of the [PGF manual](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) for even more options)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the trick. I'll mess around with various options of pdfpages to get it exactly how I want it.