# Box around different slides - LaTeX Presentation Handout

Tags: beamer, presentations

I would like to make handouts for my LaTeX presentation.

I read [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/22/beamer-series-pt5.html) how I can do this.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]
```

which produces:

[image]

However, I would like to have a border to distinguish the slides, like this:

[image]

**How can I do this?**

**EDIT:** Example code:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide A}
example 1
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide B}
example 2
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide C}
example 3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide D}
example 4
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [This page](https://wiki.bath.ac.uk/display/latextricks/Making+handouts+from+your+beamer+presentation) suggests to compile your presentation and then `\includepdf` it into a new file. The option `frame=true` looks like what you want. I cannot try this at the moment.

Comment: Or you have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53505/beamer-handout-problem-when-creating-border-around-frames).

Comment: @cauchy42  Unfortunately, it does not work for me yet...

Comment: It is easier to help you if you provide a complete small example.

Comment: @cfr See my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your MWE:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide A}
example 1
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide B}
example 2
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide C}
example 3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide D}
example 4
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Compile this (file `mypres.tex` to `mypres.pdf`, say).
Then have a second file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-last,nup=2x2,landscape=false,frame=true,
            noautoscale=true,scale=0.6,delta=0mm 5mm]{mypres.pdf}
\end{document}
```

which will contain the (framed) slides, arranged in a 2x2.

Comment: thanks, it works. Is it also possible to put a pagenumber on each page? (so if I have 4 pages of handout, it would like to have 4 page numbers).

Comment: @student441 I think the easiest way would be to have the page numbers in the frames. I don't see a solution (using `pdfpages`) to have them outside, sorry.